# Python mouse events do not work in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, mouseevent

For the past two years, whenever I've tried to run a simple code in Jupyter notebook, like this one,  I can't get it to respond to clicks.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
d
def on_click(event):
    x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
    print(f'Clicked at coordinates: ({x}, {y})')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_click)
plt.show()
```

What settings are missing?   What was changed in handling events? Before I was able to handle much more complex events. Now I have: Python 3.10.6,  notebook server is: 6.4.12, IPython 8.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me from the standard Jupyter Notebook but it seems the *%matplotlib notebook* is not working properly from within VSCode.

code from: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/244#issuecomment-682390836

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as widgets
%matplotlib notebook
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)
out = widgets.Output()

@out.capture()
def onclick(event):
    print(event)
    ax.set_title('%s click: button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' %
          ('double' if event.dblclick else 'single', event.button,
           event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata))
display(out)
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

Comment: Add an explanation of that code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).